# Add custom js in head in magento2?

Tags: layout, javascript, magento2, magento2-dev-beta, head

I have custom module. I want add file **my.js** in folder **app\code\Xanka\Slider\view\frontend\web\js\slider\my.js**.
I used code in **app\code\Xanka\Slider\view\frontend\layout\default.xml**

```
<head>
    <title>My Slideshow</title> 
    <script src="Xanka_Slider::js/slider/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"/>        
</head>
```

is not true.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if want to add js file then try this

```
 <head>
        <link src="Xanka_Slider::js/slider/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"/>
    </head>
```

***Here instead of use  using***

Answer (score 4):

use below code in

view\frontend\layout\test_index_index.xml

```
<head>
    <title>My Slideshow</title> 
   <link src="Xanka_Slider::js/slider/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"/>               
</head>
```

and then keep you js file in below path

pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Xanka_Slider/js/slider/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js

Comment: Nice, @Pradeep it works, for my added new custom module, but how could I add script or css on Home Page? Any idea.

Comment: in you theme in Magento_Theme/layout you can do it