# Add script in header in checkout page

Tags: magento2, module, checkout, javascript, header

I want to add some custom JavaScript in the header of the checkout page.
I tried to follow the layout structure..

I created a module and places my custom JS file is in `app/code/Roman/hello/view/frontend/web/js/view`

and my `checkout_index_index.xml` file is:

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">
                            Roman_hello/js/view/hello-init.js
                        </item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <!-- The new step you add -->
                                            <item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Roman_hello/js/view/js_helloworld</item>
                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

That's what I was able to pickup from different places on the web I found, but nothing seems to work..

How should I write it?

Comment: Maybe hello in module name should be uppercase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom js in head in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86243/add-custom-js-in-head-in-magento2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!!!SOLVED!!!

The `checkout_index_index.xml` file needs to have the following code:

```
<head>
       <script src="Roman_hello::js/view/hello-init.js"/> 
</head>
```

but you also need a `require-config.js` file in `<Vendor_Name>/<Module_Name>/view/frontend`

and it needs to have the following code:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            lazyloadScript:'Roman_hello::js/view/hello-init'
        }
    }
};
```

Hope this helps anyone!