# How to add custom js file before body tag in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, javascript, head, tags

> But script moving to inside body tag how to fixes this issue? Anyone
> can help me for this

```
<referenceContainer name="head.additional">
   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_js" template="Magento_Theme::html/mycustomjs.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add custom js in head in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86243/add-custom-js-in-head-in-magento2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**app/code/Vendorename/Modulename/view/frontend/layout**

**default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendorename_Modulename::css/customcss.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

> **Place your css at app/code/Vendorename/Modulenaee/view/frontend/web/css/customcss.css**